# Como fazer leitura temporizada na base de dados?

Tags: php, jquery

Boa noite,

Estou aqui a tentar enviar um valor para um ficheiro php, e receber resposta desse mesmo ficheiro, isso automaticamente. Mas algo esta a correr mal. Eu sou iniciante nesta área e tou com alguma dificuldade. Alguém por favor me consegue ajudar?

Deixo em baixo o código jQuery, está alguma coisa nele mal que não está a devolver qualquer valor.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myLast = 'sendlast='+ $("#send_total").val();
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
     jQuery.ajax({
         type: "POST", 
         url: "auto_load_news.php", 
         dataType:"text", 
         data:myLast, 

         success: function () {
             $('#have_news').load('auto_load_news.php').show("slow");
         },
         error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
             alert(thrownError);
         }
     }),
        200000
   );
});
```

```html
<?php
include("config.php");

if (isset($_POST["sendlast"])) {
    $last = filter_var($_POST["sendlast"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
  
    $result = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT idpost FROM post ORDER BY idpost DESC LIMIT 1");
    $result->execute(); // Execute prepared Query
    $result->bind_result($idposta); // Bind variables to prepared statement

    while($result->fetch()) { 
        if($idposta > $last) {
            echo "Existem novos posts";
        } else{ 
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: A cada tempo deve verificar o banco isso? O que vejo que ocorre com seu codigo é que depois de uns 20 segundos da instrução ajax vai passar  para o próximo script sem voltar para a instrução ajax.

Answer (score 0):

O seu erro está ocorrendo no código PHP, altere-o da seguinte maneira:

```
<?php
include("config.php");

if (isset($_POST["sendlast"])) {
    $last = filter_var($_POST["sendlast"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);

    $result = $mysqli->prepare('
        SELECT COUNT(`idpost`) as total
        FROM post
        WHERE `idpost` > "?"
        ORDER BY `idpost` DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ');
    $result->bind_param('i', $last);
    $result->execute();
    $row = $result->fetch();
    if($row['total'] > 0) {
        echo "Existem novos posts";
    } else {
        echo "Não existem novos posts";
    }
}
?>
```

Recomendo muito a trocar as funções mysqli para o PDO, como a utilização é bem semelhante, não terá dificuldades em aprender.

Comment: Vou experimentar. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.